# What is the right callback path for external OAuth logins in IdentityServer3?

Tags: oauth, owin, identityserver3

I'm having difficulty adding a custom OAuth middleware to a standalone IdentityServer3 instance and have it properly redirect on to my site after authentication. My custom OWIN middleware is based on examples from the [OwinOAuthProviders](https://github.com/RockstarLabs/OwinOAuthProviders) project, but am unsure whether there is a specific callback in IdentityServer3 I should point to, or how to go about registering my own.

For example, when using [Google authentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google/) there appears to be a convention of using `/root/signin-google` (mentioned [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/393)), which works just fine. But how does that endpoint work? I haven't yet been able to locate the code in the source, so that I can get something similar to `/root/signin-{IDP}` to work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The callback path is middleware specific and typically relative to the path the middleware is hosted in. Maybe check the value of `CallbackPath` on the options at startup time. Or open an issue in their repo.